# Object Not interactable while trying to scroll down a pop up using Selenium on Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to scroll down a pop up that appears in the following link https://www.vivino.com/IT/en/ronchi-di-cialla-picolit-di-cialla/w/2015576?year=2011&price_id=23500586 (or any other wine link on vivino) after clicking on 'show more reviews', but when i try to scroll i get the Element not Interactable error.
The code to open the reviews pop up is the following

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re
import time
import random



target_url = 'https://www.vivino.com/IT/it/ronchi-di-cialla-picolit-di-cialla/w/2015576?year=2011&price_id=23500586'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)




driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(target_url) #apre la pagina

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight") 

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/3);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight/3, document.body.scrollHeight*2/3);")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight*2/3, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root jss1 MuiButton-outlined jss3 MuiButton-disableElevation']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code scrolling down to each review every 1 second. I suggest you to not loop directly on reviews, i.e. don't do something like

```
reviews = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'allReviews__reviews')]/child::div")
for review in reviews:
    ...
```

because initially only few reviews are loaded, and then as you scroll down more are loaded. So if you use the code above `reviews` will only contain the first loaded reviews. The code below solves this problem, but it will fail if the number of total reviews is smaller than `limit`. So you should improve the code to take into account also this fact

```
target_url = 'https://www.vivino.com/IT/it/ronchi-di-cialla-picolit-di-cialla/w/2015576?year=2011&price_id=23500586'
driver.get(target_url)
# go to reviews section
driver.get(target_url + '#all_reviews')
# click on show more reviews
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Mostra altre recensioni')]/../..").click()
# scroll down to each review, one by one in a loop
limit = 20
for idx in range(limit):
    reviews = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'allReviews__reviews')]/child::div")
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', reviews[idx])
    time.sleep(1)
```